# JavaScript redirection to alternative index

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to change my index according to language of visitors.

I try this code but it's not working

```
<script type="type/javascript">

var language = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage;

if (language.indexOf('es') {
window.location = '../index.html';
} else {
window.location = '../index2.html';
}
</script>
```

Comment: You missed a `)` in `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

This is working ...you missed ")"

```
<script type="type/javascript">

var language = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage;

if (language.indexOf('es')>-1) {
window.location = '../index.html';
} else {
window.location = '../index2.html';
}
</script>
```

Also you have to use with condition as   @Zoli Szabo said.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider that `language.indexOf('es')` will return 0 (== false) for `'es*'` language codes, because the index of the first character is 0. If `'es'` is not found, the `indexOf()` method will return -1.

So, if your "index.html" is the spanish version and "index2.html" the international version, your code should look like this:

```
<script type="type/javascript">
var language = navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage;

if (-1 < language.indexOf('es')) {
  window.location = '../index.html';
} else {
  window.location = '../index2.html';
}
</script>
```